# Is session replication possible in tomcat, without making session attributes serializable?

Tags: tomcat, cluster-computing, session-replication

Is session replication possible in tomcat, without making session attributes serializable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Yes](http://code.google.com/p/memcached-session-manager/wiki/SerializationStrategies).

Answer (score 0):

**NO**

Please check link for explanation.

http://www.coderanch.com/t/502709/Servlets/java/store-serialized-object-session-attributes